# how to add activity indicator to ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

i use ASIHTTPRequest to get data from a RESTful web service . ASIHttpRequest add an activity indicator in the statut bar , bar i disabled the statut bar , so can i add an activity indicator in my interface ? 
thank you

Answer (score 4):

You could create it yourself by adding a semi-transparent subview with a UIActivityIndicator to your main view, and dismissing it when the ASIHTTPRequest is finished.

You could also or rely on the very cool and already made [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD) project.  Another option - considering you don't have a status bar it might be an interesting alternative, as long as the overlay is opaque - would be [MTStatusBarOverlay](https://github.com/vguerci/MTStatusBarOverlay).

Comment: Thak you .i downloaded MBProgressHUD , it seem easy to use but if i understand , ASIHttpRequest should have a selector ...I should put a selector ... Can you help me please ? i'm so new in iphone dev

Comment: Indeed, you can use a selector to define a method that will be called by ASIHTTPRequest as soon as the request is over and remove the MBProgressHUD from there, or use ASIHTTPRequest's downloadProgressDelegate to update the MBProgressHUD of the progress made by the indicator.

I would suggest you look at the code sample provided by the two projects, as they contain pretty much all you need to connect the dots. And good luck with your project!

Comment: (Also if I answered your question, feel free to approve the answer too :))